# Process multiple excel files with different number of sheets

Tags: python, pandas

I need to process a number of excel files with different # of tabs and different names. I'm creating a function to load the files with pandas, loop over the sheets, and then return a data frame.

```
def process_file(file_name):
   # just junk code - will use pandas
   for sheet_name in file_name:
     sheet_x = sheet_name
    return sheet_x

sheet_1, sheet_2 = process_file(excel_file)
```

Because there are an unknown amount of sheets in each file, trying to create a variable for each one seems manual. If I wanted to return each sheet as a variable, whether it's 2 or 10 sheets, is there a way to do that instead of naming each one?

Comment: Why do you have to unpack? `pandas.read_excel(sheet_name=None)` returns a dictionary `{'sheet_1': dataframe1,...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store all of your sheets:

```py
def process_file(file_name):
    sheets = []   
    # just junk code - will use pandas
    for sheet_name in file_name:
        sheet_x = sheet_name
        sheets.append(sheet_x)
    return sheets


sheets_to_process = []
for excel_file in files:
    sheets_to_process += process_file(excel_file)
```